# Collision detection algorithm

Tags: python, performance, collision, pygame

This is my second algorithm and I will try to make it as simple for you to understand how it works. It is pretty expensive and I'd like to make it more efficient.

[image: Visual picture of the valid points where the direction of collision is calculated at].

It works by splitting a square  into 4 sides and then by determining if an edge is within a side (which is a triangle). Then collision can respond by using collision direction as a tool to reduce velocity in the `y` or `x` axis.

```
from vector import Vector
from math_extra import Math
from utilities import util
import random

class Collisions():


    def Detect(me, ent):
            me_Pos = Vector.Add(me.GetPos(), [me.GetVelocity()[0], -me.GetVelocity()[1]]) # first entity with a predicted pos
            ent_pos     = Vector.Add(ent.GetPos(), [ent.GetVelocity()[0], -ent.GetVelocity()[1]]) # second entity with a predicted pos

            y_max, y_min, x_max, x_min = me_Pos[1] + (me.Entity.h * 0.5), me_Pos[1] - (me.Entity.h * 0.5),  me_Pos[0] + (me.Entity.w * 0.5), me_Pos[0] - (me.Entity.w * 0.5) # defining edge coordinates for the first entity
            y_max2, y_min2, x_min2, x_max2 = ent_pos[1] + (ent.Entity.h / 2), ent_pos[1] - (ent.Entity.h / 2), ent_pos[0] - (ent.Entity.w/2), ent_pos[0] + (ent.Entity.w/2) # defining edge coordinates for the second entity

            isColliding = ((x_max >= x_min2 and x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min <= x_max2 and x_min >= x_min2)) and ((y_min <= y_max2 and y_min >= y_min) or (y_max <= y_max2 and y_max >= y_min2)) # are two entitities interceting at all?

            y_range   = Math.Clamp((abs(me_Pos[0] - ent_pos[0])) / (0.5 * ent.Entity.w) * ent.Entity.h, 0, ent.Entity.h) * 0.5 # y range (refer to the picture) This defines valid y coordinate range for left and right edge
            y_range_2 = (y_range*0.5) # y range (refer to the picture) This defines valid y coordinate range for top and bottom range

            left  =  (x_max >= x_min2 and x_max <= ent_pos[0]) and ((y_min <= ent_pos[1]+y_range and y_min >= ent_pos[1]-y_range) or (y_max <= ent_pos[1]+y_range and y_max >= ent_pos[1]-y_range)) # is something hitting me from the left
            right = (x_min <= x_max2 and x_min >= ent_pos[0]) and ((y_min <= ent_pos[1]+y_range and y_min >= ent_pos[1]-y_range) or (y_max <= ent_pos[1]+y_range and y_max >= ent_pos[1]-y_range)) # is something hitting me from the right


            top    = ((x_max >= x_min2 and x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min <= x_max2 and x_min >= x_min2)) and ((y_min <= y_max2 and y_min >= ent_pos[1] + y_range_2) or (y_max <= y_max2 and y_max >= ent_pos[1] + y_range_2)) # is something hitting me from the top

            bottom    = ((x_max >= x_min2 and x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min <= x_max2 and x_min >= x_min2)) and ((y_max >= y_min2 and y_max <= ent_pos[1] - y_range_2) or (y_min >= y_min2 and y_min <= ent_pos[1] - y_range_2))# is something hitting me top


            Collisions.Response(me, ent, [isColliding, left, right, top, bottom]) # respond to the collision

            return isColliding, left, right, top, bottom # return data about the collision

    def Response(me, ent, physdata):
        isColliding, left, right, top, bottom = physdata[0], physdata[1], physdata[2], physdata[3], physdata[4]

        me_Pos  = me.GetPos()
        ent_Pos = ent.GetPos()
        me_Velocity = me.GetVelocity()

        if left   == True:
            me.SetVelocity([me_Velocity[0] * -0.2, me_Velocity[1]])
        if right  == True:
            me.SetVelocity([me_Velocity[0] * -0.2, me_Velocity[1]])
        if top    ==  True:
            me.SetVelocity([me_Velocity[0], me_Velocity[1] * -0.2])
        if bottom == True:
            me.SetVelocity([me_Velocity[0], me_Velocity[1] * -0.2])


        y_max, y_min, x_max, x_min = me_Pos[1] + (me.Entity.h * 0.5), me_Pos[1] - (me.Entity.h * 0.5),  me_Pos[0] + (me.Entity.w * 0.5), me_Pos[0] - (me.Entity.w * 0.5) # again defining coordinates for edges

        for x in [x_max, x_min]: # looping through all edges and seeing if the distance between them and center of entity two is less than the radius
            for y in [y_max, y_min]:
                colliding, byDistance = util.isInSphere([x,y], ent.GetPos(), ent.Entity.w * 0.5 )

                if colliding:

                    me.Entity.move_ip(Vector.Multiply(Vector.Normalize(Vector.Sub(me.GetRealPos(),ent.GetRealPos())), 1+byDistance)) # if so then move the entity in other direction
        Collisions.Stuck_Response(me, ent)
    def Stuck_Response(me,ent):

        if Vector.Distance(me.GetRealPos(), ent.GetRealPos()) < me.Entity.w * 0.7:
            me.Entity.move_ip(random.randint(1,2), random.randint(1,2))
            me.Entity.move_ip(Vector.Sub(me.GetRealPos(), ent.GetRealPos()))


    def Translate(table): # loops through all entities and checks for collision with all of them
        for k, v in enumerate(table):
            for k2, v2 in enumerate(table):
                ent_one = table[k]
                ent_two = table[k2]
                if ent_one != ent_two: # don't collide myself with myself
                    Collisions.Detect(ent_one, ent_two)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do? What arguments do they take? What do they return?
2. The long lines mean that we can't read the code here without scrolling it. The Python style guide (PEP8) [recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) sticking to 79 characters.
3. In Python it's good practice to use object attributes instead of getter functions. Using `me.pos` and `me.velocity` would make the code easier to read.
4. The code start with objects called `me` and `ent`, computes positions `me_Pos` and `ent_pos` (consistent apart from the capitalization), but then goes on to compute `x_min` and `x_min2`. Later on there are `ent_one` and `ent_two`. It is hard to remember which of these goes with `me` and which with `ent`. More consistency in naming would help.
5. The predicted position is computed like this:

   ```
   Vector.Add(me.GetPos(), [me.GetVelocity()[0], -me.GetVelocity()[1]])
   ```

   Why is the y component of the velocity inverted? It would be better to store it the other way round so you could write:

   ```
   Vector.Add(me.GetPos(), me.GetVelocity())
   ```
6. It's wrong to add a position to a velocity: the dimensions don't match. Velocity is the *rate* of change of position: it needs to be multiplied by a timestep in order to get a change of position. Presumably your code happens to work because your velocities are measured *per frame* and so the timestep is always 1. But this is inflexible: it means that if you ever need to change your framerate then you have to change all the velocities. Better to measure velocities *per second*.
7. The code would be much easier to read if the `Vector` class supported arithmetic operations (which is easy to do in Python using [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), [`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__) and other special methods. You'd then be able to compute the predicted position like this:

   ```
   me.pos + me.velocity * timestep
   ```
8. The code could make more use of vectors. If an object's size were stored as a vector (instead of a pair of attributes `w` and `h`) then you could compute the axis-aligned bounding box more simply, perhaps like this:

   ```
   halfsize = me.size / 2
   bounding_box = me.pos - halfsize, me.pos + halfsize
   ```
9. This code repeatedly computes each object's axis-aligned bounding box before each collision. This is a waste of effort: better to compute this information once per frame and remember it.
10. The code in `Stuck_Response` relies on the objects having square bounding boxes (it only uses `w`). So why have `h` at all?
11. The strategy you're following here is to move the objects and then test to see if they intersect in their updated positions. This has a problem, which is that objects can pass through each other. Consider a timestep like this, with two objects in their initial positions and their movement vectors shown:

    [image]

    The updated positions of the objects don't intersect:

    [image]

    But a look at the *swept paths* of the two objects shows that at some point during the timestep they must have collided:

    [image]

    See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228915/68063) on Stack Overflow for some advice on finding collisions between moving convex polygons.
12. The code in `Translate` compares every pair of objects. This means that it won't be able to handle very many objects before it starts to slow down due to the \$Θ(n^2)\$ runtime. Better to use some kind of spatial lookup structure like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to quickly find candidate collisions.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you are using a class only as a container of methods. There is no state associated. In such conditions, using plain methods is less confusing.

However, looking at your `Translate` method, you could use your class as an extension of a list that perform collision detection on its own items. Something along the lines of:

```
class Collisions(list):
    def Translate(self):
        for elem in self:
            # do something with elem.
```

Talking about `Translate`, you should have a look at the [`itertools.permutation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) generator. However, considering two elements `A` and `B` contained in the list of collisionable items, I don't think it is efficient to perform collision detection between `A` and `B` to update `A` and then, latter on, perform collision detection between `B` and `A` to update `B`. You might want to iterate over each couple only once and call

```
Collision.Response(me, ent, [isColliding, left, right, top, bottom])
Collision.Response(ent, me, [isColliding, left, right, top, bottom])
```

or whatever parameters you see fit. In the meantime, you'd want to use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

---

Some remarks on your style:

- As @Kai suggested, try to reduce the length of your lines; on way of doing it is condensing `a > b_min and a < b_max` kinds of tests by `b_min < a < b_max`;
- Some names sounds badly chosen; try `perform_detection` instead of `Translate` or `save_new_position` instead of `Stuck_Response`; avoid title case for function names;
- Why using a `list` to pass parameters around to `Response` if you are just unpacking them right after?
- You are computing `isColliding` but never using it…

---

Proposed improvement:

```
import random
from itertools import permutations
from vector import Vector
from math_extra import Math
from utilities import util

class Collisions(list):
    def perform_detection(self): # loops through all entities and checks for collision with all of them
        # Use combinations_with_replacement(self) if you see fit.
        for entity1, entity2 in permutations(self,2):
            Collisions.detect(entity1, entity2)

    @staticmethod
    def detect(me, ent):
        # first entity with a predicted pos
        me_Pos = Vector.Add(me.GetPos(), [me.GetVelocity()[0], -me.GetVelocity()[1]])
        # second entity with a predicted pos
        ent_pos = Vector.Add(ent.GetPos(), [ent.GetVelocity()[0], -ent.GetVelocity()[1]])

        # defining edge coordinates for the first entity
        y_max = me_Pos[1] + (me.Entity.h/2)
        y_min = me_Pos[1] - (me.Entity.h/2)
        x_max = me_Pos[0] + (me.Entity.w/2)
        x_min = me_Pos[0] - (me.Entity.w/2)

        # defining edge coordinates for the second entity
        y_max2 = ent_pos[1] + (ent.Entity.h/2)
        y_min2 = ent_pos[1] - (ent.Entity.h/2)
        x_min2 = ent_pos[0] - (ent.Entity.w/2)
        x_max2 = ent_pos[0] + (ent.Entity.w/2) 

        # does two entities intersect at all?
        isColliding = ((x_min2 <= x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min2 <= x_min <= x_max2)) and
            ((y_min2 <= y_min <= y_max2) or (y_min2 <= y_max <= y_max2)) 

        # valid y coordinate range for left and right edge
        y_range = Math.Clamp(abs(me_Pos[0] - ent_pos[0]) / (ent.Entity.w/2) * ent.Entity.h, 0, ent.Entity.h) / 2
        y_range_2 = y_range / 2

        # is something hitting me from the left
        left = (x_min2 <= x_max <= ent_pos[0]) and
            ((ent_pos[1]-y_range <= y_min <= ent_pos[1]+y_range) or
                (ent_pos[1]-y_range <= y_max <= ent_pos[1]+y_range))
        # is something hitting me from the right
        right = (ent_pos[0] <= x_min <= x_max2) and
            ((ent_pos[1]-y_range <= y_min <= ent_pos[1]+y_range) or
                (ent_pos[1]-y_range <= y_max <= ent_pos[1]+y_range))
        # is something hitting me from the top
        top = ((x_min2 <= x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min2 <= x_min <= x_max2 )) and
            ((ent_pos[1] + y_range_2 <= y_min <= y_max2) or (ent_pos[1] + y_range_2 <= y_max <= y_max2)) 
        # is something hitting me from the bottom
        bottom = ((x_min2 <= x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min2 <= x_min <= x_max2)) and
            ((y_min2 <= y_max <= ent_pos[1] - y_range_2) or (y_min2 <= y_min <= ent_pos[1] - y_range_2))

        Collisions.compute_movement(
            me, ent,
            (x_max, x_min), (y_max, y_min),
            isColliding, left, right, top, bottom)

    @staticmethod
    def compute_movement(me, ent, x_bounds, y_bounds, isColliding, left, right, top, bottom):
        me_Pos  = me.GetPos()
        ent_Pos = ent.GetPos()
        me_Velocity = me.GetVelocity()

        if left or right:
            me.SetVelocity([me_Velocity[0] * -0.2, me_Velocity[1]])
        if top or bottom:
            me.SetVelocity([me_Velocity[0], me_Velocity[1] * -0.2])

        radius = ent.Etity.w / 2
        for x in x_bounds: # looping through all edges and seeing if the distance between them and center of entity two is less than the radius
            for y in y_bounds:
                colliding, byDistance = util.isInSphere([x,y], me_pos, radius)

                if colliding:
                    me.Entity.move_ip(Vector.Multiply(
                        Vector.Normalize(Vector.Sub(me.GetRealPos(),ent.GetRealPos())),
                        1 + byDistance)) # if so then move the entity in other direction

        if Vector.Distance(me.GetRealPos(), ent.GetRealPos()) < me.Entity.w * 0.7:
            me.Entity.move_ip(random.randint(1,2), random.randint(1,2))
            me.Entity.move_ip(Vector.Sub(me.GetRealPos(), ent.GetRealPos()))
```

However `compute_movement` does not really need to be a method unless you use it several times in conjunction with `combinations_with_replacement` as stated above.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! The computational time nearly decreased by 200%.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could improve code style by limiting the line length.

e.g.

```
        bottom    = ((x_max >= x_min2 and x_max <= x_max2) or (x_min <= x_max2 and x_min >= x_min2)) and ((y_max >= y_min2 and y_max <= ent_pos[1] - y_range_2) or (y_min >= y_min2 and y_min <= ent_pos[1] - y_range_2))
```

is really hard to read you have to scroll it (even in any IDE) horizontally. My suggestion is to break it at `and` and `or`

Moreover, adding comments to your code would help a lot to understand what's going on ;-)

Comment: I added comments now!